# If a caster has several clones lying in wait, can they choose which one to revive into?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, character-death

A cautious caster has made several [clones](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/clone.htm) (as the 8th level wizard/sorcerer spell) in safe-houses to revive into, then died.

Can they choose which clone to revive into?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the level 8 Wizard spell Clone?

Answer (score 5):

**Sort of.**

The clone spell does not permit you to create a backup which you will simply wake up in if you die. The precise wording is:

> Once the spell is cast, the duplicate must be grown in a laboratory for 2d4 months.
>
> When the clone is completed, the original’s soul enters it immediately, if that creature is already dead.
>
> ...
>
> A duplicate can be grown while the original still lives, or when the original soul is unavailable, but the resulting body is merely a soulless bit of inert flesh, which rots if not preserved.

You only come back to life in a cloned body if you are *already dead* at the moment that the moment that the clone finishes growing. If you're not dead, no transferral happens, and the clone is just a "soulless bit of inert flesh". Effectively, the spell has failed.

**However...**

Say the cautious caster went round their safehouses casting the *Clone* spell using a chunk of their flesh in each location and then went off to do something absurdly dangerous. They die before any of their clones have finished growing. Now, assuming the laboratories are properly tended by assistants or at least undisturbed and the clones permitted to complete their growth, at the moment each clone becomes fully grown, the spell would take effect and permit the caster to be resurrected in that clone body. The character could effectively choose which body to wake up in by being unwilling to return until the right clone activates. However, there is a 2-8 month latency on that selection, so the caster may be waiting some time before they can get back into action.

This changes in 5e, where the clone spell explicitly does create a backup body which you will transfer to if you die. In 3.5, the wording clearly does not support that.